# Can I upload video to Facebook from within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, facebook

In the past, I've been able to upload images and text to Facebook from within my iPhone application, but I have not been able to upload video.  Does anyone know how to programmatically upload video to Facebook?

Comment: Answers should be shared here on StackOverflow, so that others may benefit from them too. This is a community site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be able to make a [facebook.video.upload](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Video.upload) FBRequest call, similar to how photos are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample for photo upload, I guess similar with video, but seems like more limitation for video.

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"me.png"]; 


  NSMutableDictionary * params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  img1, @"picture",
                                  nil];

  [_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"photos.upload" 
                         andParams: params1
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                       andDelegate: self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Working implementation using TheRonin's answer and the link to Zoul's code on Github can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936214/iphone-a-problem-with-uploading-video-to-facebook).