# iPhone - A problem with uploading video to facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, uploading

I am having a problem uploading a video to facebook.

Last month, it worked OK.

I can still log in to FaceBook with my appKey and appSecretKey, but if I request 'facebook.video.upload' method to facebook, the site does not reply.

In the past, it worked perfectly.

What is the problem? Has FaceBook updated the interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I use FBVideoUpload ([source code here](https://github.com/zoul/facebook-ios-sdk/)) and it works fine, so I put my code here:

```
m_Facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
m_FacebookUploader = [[FBVideoUpload alloc]init]; 
NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil];
m_Facebook.forceOldStyleAuth = YES;
[m_Facebook authorize:APP_ID permissions:permissions delegate:self];
```

In Facebook delegate methods

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:m_MoviePath];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Look at my funny video !", @"title",
                            @"A message", @"description",
                            nil];

    [m_FacebookUploader setApiKey:APP_ID];
    [m_FacebookUploader setAccessToken:m_Facebook.accessToken];
    [m_FacebookUploader setAppSecret:APP_SECRET];
    [m_FacebookUploader startUploadWithURL:movieURL params:params delegate:self];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help. I found a lot of code similar to yours. But they doesn't work perfectly. My app works fine with your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: right folks after spending at least a couple of days on this with no success, I can say that Zoul's code is the only approach I have found to work. The link to Zoul's source is in TheRonin's answer here.